How to authenticate during local development using an identity provider in Azure App Service
We have a deployment pipeline for our Azure App Service (python runtime) with a Microsoft Entra ID identity provider for authentication. This works fine in the cloud, but we want to be able to use the same authentication pattern while developing locally.
We are using some of the user claims in the request headers in our backend to identify the client and to authorize the client to access certain information. For example, we are using X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME to display the user name in the UI. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-user-identities)
However, these user claims are not available in a local development environment. We are struggling to 'simulate' the authentication flow which happens in the cloud in our development environment so that we can properly test certain security features before deploying.
We are looking into whether MSAL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/python/) is a solution, but we cannot quite figure out how to solve this problem. Any ideas on this?

Alternatively, you can make use of MSAL by calling /me Microsoft Graph endpoint to get signed-in username.

Alternatively, you can make use of MSAL to generate access token using delegated flow and call /me Microsoft Graph endpoint to get signed-in username.
In my case, I registered one Entra ID application and granted User.Read permission of Delegated type as below:

To get access token using interactive flow, enable public client flow and add http://localhost as redirect URI in mobile/desktop platform:

When I ran below python code, it opened browser to pick an account to sign in:
import msal
import requests

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "appId"
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'

scope = ["User.Read"]

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
)

result = None

accounts = app.get_accounts()
if accounts:
    chosen = accounts[0]
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=chosen)

if not result:
    result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scope)

if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result["access_token"]
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
    response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', headers=headers)
    data = response.json()

    print("Signed-in user display name:", data.get('displayName'))
    print("Signed-in user name:", data.get('userPrincipalName'))
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))


After successful authentication, you will get signed-in username in console response successfully like this:


Thanks for your answer, we will be testing this shortly! What we have now as a preliminary solution is a Powershell script which uses az account show to retrieve user info into environment variables and then store that into Flask config while running in debug mode.
